# Is it always necessary to be "finished with"?

Tags: prepositions, spoken-english

Is it grammatically incorrect to say "done school" or "finished school"? For example,

> - I am done school, *or*
> - I am finished school.

Must I always use the word *with* to be grammatically correct?

Answer (score 3):

It depends what point you are trying to convey. If you are trying to express your frustration with school (and want to say that you're sick of it) then you would say *I'm finished **with** school!* or *I'm done **with** school!* So, yes, in this case you would have to use "with".

If you want to say that you have finished school (i.e. completed Year 12 or been dismissed for the day) then you would say *I **have** finished school*.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The short answer is: with "be", the "with" is necessary, and with "have", it's optional. That doesn't depend on what point you're trying to convey. The wording here suggests that "with" expresses frustration with its object, which is not true.